# ¿como cambio de color un canvas con un clic en html5?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Disculpe pero quisiera saber como puedo hacer para cambiar de color un dibujo en canvas por el metodo de darle clic al dibujo.
Es para otro tipo trabajo pero solo quiero el metodo de darle un clic al dibujo y que realize una accion.

Comment: Hola Lennox y bienvenido a [es.so]. Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, coloca algo de código para poder ayudarte. Selecciona [editar](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
  ctx.fill();
  canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if(e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft > 10 && e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft < 210){
      if(e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop > 10 && e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop < 210){
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
        ctx.fill();
      }
    } 
  },false);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Un canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
        <canvas width="1080" height="720" id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Tienes que añadir un eventListener y luego buscar en que zona de la pantalla se ha hecho click, este ejemplo superpone un cuadrado rojo sobre el otro.